# Where can I find a Spotify .deb package?

Tags: software-installation, repository, music, spotify

It appears to me that Spotify have released a Linux client... however every attempt I've made to get it from the repositries have failed. It would really help me if someone could provide a .deb package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is available from spotify repo http://repository.spotify.com. Just follow this article: http://linuxhub.net/2010/07/linux-gets-spotify-love-install-spotify-in-ubuntu/.

Please note that the first step in the above url is `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` .

If the instructions on above url  fails then you can directly download the .deb package from http://repository.spotify.com/pool/non-free/s/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Spotify for the time being is supported for 10.04 Lucid. In the official Spotify for Linux page;[*http://www.spotify.com/int/download/previews/*](http://www.spotify.com/int/download/previews/), there is a simple list of instruction to install Spotify in Ubuntu. Jump over and check it out :)

The first step to installation is the same as @aneeshep answer ;) :`sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`